# configuring webpack in yarn workspaces

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am migrating some repos to a monorepo that uses yarn workspaces with Lerna. The packages look roughly like this:

```
|-- packages
    |-- app
    |-- components-1 
    |-- components-2
```

`app` is bundled with webpack. It includes both `components-1` and `components-2` as dependencies, as well as React 15.3.2.

`components-1` includes a peer dependency of React 15.6.1. So it has React 15.6.1 is a dev dependency. This is needed for running react-styleguidist and tests from within that package, and is mostly an artifact from its existence as a separate repo, pre-migration.

It seems that, because there are two versions of React, webpack will bundle both because both resolve successfully at different locations. React 15.3.2 gets installed in the repo's root-level `node_modules`, while React 15.6.1 gets installed in `components-1/node_modules`.

The same occurs for ReactDOM, as one might expect.

My solution has been to define aliases for `react` and `react-dom` in the app's webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'react': path.resolve('../../node_modules/react'),
    'react-dom': path.resolve('../../node_modules/react-dom'),
  },
}
```

But this seems a bit hacky to me, since it will only work within this yarn workspaces set up.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, either in the webpack config off the app, or in some kind of yarn workspaces configuration.

Answer (score 0):

webpack determines module uniqueness based on its file path. Therefore, if you have two copies of react, coming from two separate node modules paths, then yes, webpack will bundle both. However, if you say you are using yarn workspaces, this should mean that your monorepo should only have one `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct that a monorepo using yarn workspaces should have only one node_modules folder. There should be one at the root level of the repo, and one in each package.

Comment: What happens when two packages use different versions of React? For example I have a common library on react 16.13 and a project on react 16.8. How's this handled?